# Finding the largest odd number among 3 variable, program doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am new to programming and I made a program for a finger exercise in the book "Introduction to computation and programming using python"

here's the finger exercise : Write a program that examines three variables—x, y, and z—
and prints the largest odd number among them. If none of them are odd, it
should print a message to that effect.

I made this,

```
l = []

x = int(input("Enter a number for x: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number for y: "))
z = int(input("Enter a number for z: "))

l.append(x)
l.append(y)
l.append(z)

def testodd(n):
  return n%2 != 0

def maxodd (l):
  oddlist = []
  for i in l:
    if testodd(i):
      oddlist.append(i)
    else:
      continue
  return max(oddlist)

print(maxodd(l))
```

Program sometimes work properly and sometimes not for example I gave x=231 y=23 and z=678 it says "none of them are odd" what's the problem about this program ?

Comment: Suppose x,y,z are 3,4,6. None of your conditions is satisfied, because you are checking if `x` is odd and it is greater than `y` and greater than `z`. You need to check if `x` is odd and greater than or equal to other values *that are also odd*.

Comment: I would recommend you to put them in a list and iterate through it. While iterating, you can apply conditions to check an odd number and check the maximum value

Comment: You are checking whether the largest number is odd, not which odd number is the largest.

Answer (score 1):

First we create a `list` that will contain all the numbers, then we sort that list in descending order (`reverse=True`) and then we look if there is any odd number. If we don't find any odd number in the list we print the message:

```py
numbers = []
for _ in range(3):                                 # Iterate 3 times
    numbers.append(int(input("Enter a number:")))  # Append 1 number each time
numbers.sort(reverse=True)                         # Sort the numbers in descending order

for n in numbers:   # Iterate over the numbers
    if n % 2 != 0:  # If the number is odd we have found the maximum odd value
        print(n)    # Print the value
        break       # Finish the loop
else:               # An else block in a for loop will execute if no break was found
    print("none of them are odd")  # Print the message
```

A more advanced way to retrieve the numbers would be:

```py
numbers = sorted((int(input("Enter a number:")) for _ in range(3)), reverse=True)
```

that would replace the first 4 lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler if you put **only the odd numbers** into a list.

```
x = int(input("Enter a number for x: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number for y: "))
z = int(input("Enter a number for z: "))

odd_numbers = [value for value in (x,y,z) if value%2]
if odd_numbers:
    print("The greatest odd number is", max(odd_numbers))
else:
    print("None of the numbers is odd.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The program finds the maximal number and checks if it's odd.

To find the maximal odd number, you can use list comprehension:

1. Put the numbers to check at a list `numbers = [x, y, z]`
2. Loop over the numbers `t for t in numbers`, and filter in those who are odd `if t % 2 != 0`.
3. Find the maximal among them (#2): `max([t for t in numbers if t % 2 != 0])`

```
x = int(input("Enter a number for x: "))
y = int(input("Enter a number for y: "))
z = int(input("Enter a number for z: "))

# Put numbers in a list
numbers = [x, y, z]

# Filter the odd numbers, and find the max
print(max([t for t in numbers if t % 2 != 0]))
```

Comment: @PyotrVanNostrand it's each of the items in the list `numbers` that we iterate over using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may just append all numbers entered into a list, sort all odds into another list and get the maximum value:

```
numbs = []
x = int(input("Enter a number for x: "))
numbs.append(x)
y = int(input("Enter a number for y: "))
numbs.append(y)
z = int(input("Enter a number for z: "))
numbs.append(z)

odds = [x for x in numbs if x%2==1]
if odds == []:
    print('No odd number was entered')
else:
    print(max(odds))
```